# Objective C:: How to check if the user already installed your app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, viber

I am new to iOS (iphone and ipad) development.

I am developing an app. In the app, at 1 point, I will need to retrieve the contact lists, and my question is, after I get the user's contact list, is it possible to check each user have/have not installed my app? If yes, how? If no, how does Viber works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have a database with phone numbers. And I guess they send all the phonenumbers in your contacts to a server and return those who use viber. But I'm just guessing, never installed their app.

From their FAQ:

> You don't have to register! You know
>   your phone number, and so do your
>   friends, so why bother with yet
>   another username and password? Viber
>   uses your phone number as your
>   "identity" and lets you make free
>   Viber phone calls to any of your
>   friends that have Viber - using THEIR
>   phone number.

Comment: This is indeed how Viber works. Please note, though, if you do intend to upload phone numbers from a user's contacts, let them know you're doing it and give them an option to opt out. At the end of the day, if every app started uploading all my phone numbers without my knowledge or consent, I'd be pretty angry. Who knows how they're going to use that information? I'm actually quite surprised Apple allow it in the first place, considering their other restrictions.

Comment: Thank you fluchtpunkt. I think that solved/answered my question. Hi, Jasarien, why are you so sure that, "thats how Viber works"? Are you, by any chance, one of the developers from Viber?

Answer (score 0):

From strictly the point of view of checking if another application is already installed,I made use of UIPasteBoard once.We developed a standard of pasting some info based on a key and the app would check first if that particular app name is present it would not show that in offers